# Update Angular2 PrimeNG version 1.1.4 to last version

Tags: angular, typescript, version, primeng

I'm relatively new to angular2, so I was wondering how could I update my version(1.1.4) to last version!

I'm working on version 2.0.0-rc.5 of angular2.

Already tried

```
npm install primeng --save
```

but package.json still holds this value: ""primeng": "^1.1.4","

the package.json from the root directory of angular, and also of the primeng in node_modules directory

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For future references:
Had to uninstall with:

```
npm uninstall primeng --save
```

Run the code below to avoid unnecessary errors:

```
npm cache verify
```

And then install with the version you want

```
npm install primeng@x.x.x --save
```

thanks for you answer though

Comment: Use "`import {SidebarModule} from 'primeng/components/sidebar/sidebar';`" 


instead "`import { SidebarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';`"

Answer (score 3):

You only need run `npm update --save` into the folder that contains your `package.json`

Before:

```
"dependencies": {
   ....
    "primeng": "^1.1.4",
   ....
 },
```

After:

```
"dependencies": {
    ....
   "primeng": "^2.0.5",
    ....
 },
```

> Note: this command update whole your dependencies...

Answer (score -1):

Use "`import {SidebarModule} from 'primeng/components/sidebar/sidebar';`"

instead "`import { SidebarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';`"

Comment: what? he is just wanting to upgrade the version.. and nothing else... I guess.

Comment: Yes @Aman. It is just asking to update. It works for me perfectly!